# How to make a Ruby file (in a gem) executable from anywhere like a regular command?

Tags: ruby, linux, command-line-interface

I have a command in my gem: `bin/tennis`. Currently to execute it you have to **cd** into the gem and run `bin/tennis`. I was wondering is it possible to make it work like a regular shell command? i.e able to run it from any dir.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? "compile" means "translate from one language to another". Obviously, you want to compile from Ruby, but what do you want to compile "to"? And what does "able to run it from any dir" have to do with compilation? Also, what *exactly* do you mean by "make it work by any regular shell command"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is globally executable, lies under one of the directories in the `$PATH` variable (`%PATH%` on Windows).

For example, `$PATH` may look like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims:/Users/casraf/bin:/Users/casraf/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/fzf/bin
```

You may add directories to this list, separating with `:`, and each of these paths will be looked into when executing a command globally.

So you could either:

1. Save a copy of the executable in the gem exec dir:

   `ln -s /your/bin/file $(ruby -rubygems -e 'puts Gem.dir')`

   This will create a symbolic link to your bin, inside the regular gem executable dir (it should already be in your `$PATH`, if not, just add it:

   `export PATH=$(ruby -rubygems -e 'puts Gem.dir'):$PATH`

   You can put this in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` to make sure it happens on every terminal session (if you have a non-standard setup, you may need to find another file to put this in)
2. Or just add the regular path to your PATH variable:

   `PATH=/path/to/gem/bin:$PATH`